# want to use One Button as backsapce for 2 seperate Edit Text?

Tags: java, android, button, android-edittext

I want to use One Button as backspace for 2 seperate Edit Text 
I mean when focus on the (edit text) can i use the button on it.....

I can't use if statement with it (i am new on android developing)

**This is my code**

```
        bak.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
             if (et1.hasFocus()) {
              }
            String str = et1.getText().toString();
            if (str.length() > 1) {
                str = str.substring(0, str.length() - 1);
                et1.setText(str);
            } else if (str.length() <= 1) {
                et1.setText("");
            }
        }

    });
    bak.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (et2.hasFocus()){
             }
            String str2 = et2.getText().toString();
            if (str2.length() > 1) {
                str2 = str2.substring(0, str2.length() - 1);
                et2.setText(str2);
            } else if (str2.length() <= 1) {
                et2.setText("");
            }
        }
    });
```

**but my another code for  for another button work fine (why?)**

```
   BT9.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (et2.hasFocus()) {
                et2.append("9");
            }
            if (et1.hasFocus()) {
                et1.append("9");
            }
            if (ans.hasFocus()) {
                ans.append("9");
            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: "i cant use if statement with it" – Why not, exactly?

Comment: i cant = i don't know how :)

Comment: Well, you did it for the other button... :-)

Comment: but the other button was easy something maybe i need to sleep :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in your code is that you are setting OnClickListener on same button two times. The second OnClickListener will overwrite first one. So we need to do it in single OnClickListener. 
Pls try below code

```
 bak.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            EditText focusEditText=et1;
            if (et1.hasFocus()) {
                focusEditText=et1;
            }
            if (et2.hasFocus()){
                focusEditText=et2;
            }
            String str = focusEditText.getText().toString();
            if (str.length() > 1) {
                str = str.substring(0, str.length() - 1);
                focusEditText.setText(str);
            } else if (str.length() <= 1) {
                focusEditText.setText("");
            }
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should write your code as below:

```
bak.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           if (et1.hasFocus()) {
           }

            String str = et1.getText().toString();
            if (str.length() > 1) {
                str = str.substring(0, str.length() - 1);
                et1.setText(str);
            } else if (str.length() <= 1) {
                et1.setText("");
            }

            ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

            if (et2.hasFocus()){
            }

            String str2 = et2.getText().toString();
            if (str2.length() > 1) {
                str2 = str2.substring(0, str2.length() - 1);
                 et2.setText(str2);
            } else if (str2.length() <= 1) {
                 et2.setText("");
            }    
        }    
    });
```